# Bash: Finding Powerset of array

Tags: bash, permutation

I need a Bash script that will get an array with n elements as input and return the powerset of that array.

So for `array=(a, b, c, d)` the output should be

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abd
ac
acd
b
bc
bcd
c
cd
d
```

Note that no element should repeat (aab, accd, abbc are not valid) and that abc is the same as cba (the order is not important).

Every solution to similar problems I found gives either a fixed length (combination of length 2 or 3) or allows repetition (like aacd), even for other languages (not that I can do much with other languages either...)

I came up with this:

```
string='a b c d'
read -a array <<< "$string"
count="${#array[@]}"
level=0
for (( level = 0; level < $count; level++ )); do
  for (( i = $level; i < $count; i++ )); do
    output+=" ${array[$i]}"
    echo $output
  done
output=''
done
```

and my output is

```
a
a b
a b c
a b c d
b
b c
b c d
c
c d
d
```

It's missing some entries like ac, ad, abd...

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks more like a powerset than permutations.

Comment: Does it need to be in Bash? There's a very trivial way to accomplish this in Python.

Comment: _"abc is the same as cba (the order is not important)."_  Then, it is _not_ a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).  Possibly, you are looking for [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)?

Comment: Never heard of powersets, @melpomene. I'll look at that.

Comment: @pzp yes, I need a bash solution. I know it can be easily done with other languages, I've found plenty of examples, but I need it in bash :(

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done straight-forwardly just as in any other programming language by interpreting each subset as a binary number where each bit indicates whether the respective element is chosen or not.  For an *n*-element set, you count from 0 to 2<sup>*n*</sup> −1 and take the *j*-th item into the *i*-th subset if and only if the *j*-th bit in the binary representation of *i* is set.

```
#! /bin/bash

items=(a b c d)
n=${#items[@]}
powersize=$((1 << $n))

i=0
while [ $i -lt $powersize ]
do
    subset=()
    j=0
    while [ $j -lt $n ]
    do
        if [ $(((1 << $j) & $i)) -gt 0 ]
        then
            subset+=("${items[$j]}")
        fi
        j=$(($j + 1))
    done
    echo "'${subset[@]}'"
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Output:

```
''
'a'
'b'
'a b'
'c'
'a c'
'b c'
'a b c'
'd'
'a d'
'b d'
'a b d'
'c d'
'a c d'
'b c d'
'a b c d'
```

Comment: I seem to be unable to answer any question related to shell-scripting without getting completely golfed-out soon…  (Yet I believe that mine is the only solution so far that will work with arbitrary complex items.)

Comment: Your explanation is great. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "complex items"? Can I use an array as element, maybe? If so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, Bash does not support arrays of arrays AFAIK.  But you can, for example, have functions, awkward strings containing white space, parenthesis, commas and even new-lines.  But if you want `subset` to actually behave as an array, I've just found that I have missed a pair of parenthesis.  I'll fix that in a minute.

Comment: A great answer, but I encourage you to streamline it by using arithmetic conditionals (`(( i < powersize ))`) and increments (`(( ++i ))`).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your array is a set of "simple" elements, there's an interesting solution involving `eval`ing a dynamically generated brace expression.

```
$ array=(a b c d)
$ printf -v br "{%s,}" "${array[@]}"
$ echo $br
{a,}{b,}{c,}{d,}
$ eval "printf '%s\\n' $br"
```

(It omits the empty string which would be the part of every powerset, but you can add that manually afterwards.)

Comment: What do you mean by "simple elements"? And, thinking about it, could we expand to use an array as one of the elements? ;)

Comment: Great solution (for small arrays). I think you can use this for any array elements using `printf -v br '{%q,}'` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
$ p(){ eval echo $(printf "{%s,}" "$@"); }
$ p a b c d
abcd abc abd ab acd ac ad a bcd bc bd b cd c d
```

Or, more portable:

```
p() {
        [ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo; return; }
        ( shift; p "$@" ) | while read a ; do printf '%b' "$1$a\n$a\n"; done
}
p "$@"
```

Call it as this (use echo if you want one line):

```
$ echo $(p a b c d e)
abcde bcde acde cde abde bde ade de abce bce ace ce abe be ae e abcd bcd acd cd abd bd ad d abc bc ac c ab b a<br>
```

Note: It works for "complex" values of items, just don't use echo.

```
$ p " a b " "-c d-" "gg hh"
 a b -c d-gg hh
-c d-gg hh
 a b gg hh
gg hh
 a b -c d-
-c d-
 a b
```

---

And, a non-recursive option (albeit slower) based in the binary representation of each value. It is, however, mostly bash, as it makes extensive use of Arithmetic Expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

powerset(){
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && { echo "Missing set of arguments" >&2; exit 2; }
local n ns; (( n=$#, ns=1<<n ))

for (( i=1; i<ns ; i++ )); do
    a=''; # printf "%4.4s " "$i"
    for (( j=1; j<=n; j++ )); do
    (( i & 1<<(j-1) )) && a="${a}""${!j}" ;
    done
    echo "$a"
done
}

powerset "$@"
```

Remove the comment symbol (#) after the `a=''` if you need numbered results.

Answer (score 2):

building on top of the earlier answers with eval

```
eval echo $(sed 's/./{&,}/g' <<< "abcd") | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
```

will give you

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abd
ac
acd
ad
b
bc
bcd
bd
c
cd
d
```

Comment: I like the sort option. I hadn't though that sorting would be an issue or that it could be useful. Thank you.